# Google and URL 301 Redirect Allowed in this case?

Tags: magento, redirect, seo

We had a multi store set up on magento platform, with a separate domain attached to each store.

Now we have changed to a different platform, we kept the most popular domain (call domain1) for the store, but the other 2 (domain2,and domain3) i have redirected with 301 to domain1's sub-category.

Example:

domain2 and domain 3 is now redirected to domain1/category1 and domain3 is to domain1/category2

Is that allowed by google? We don't want to manipulate any results, just to keep the good old domain names linked to the only store somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

301 redirection a domain to sub category is fine. Beside redirection, you can also tell Google in webmastertool, domain 2 and 3 has been pointed to a new location.